# How to set up ProGuard for Amazon IAP?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, proguard

I'm trying to set up a basic ProGuard with Amazon IAP integrated. However when I'm trying to export my APK, I got the following errors:

```
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc]   Class       = [com/amazon/inapp/purchasing/KiwiResponseHandler$PurchaseResponseHandlerRunnable]
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc]   Method      = [run()V]
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [java/lang/String] (with 4 known super classes) and [com/amazon/inapp/purchasing/KiwiPurchaseResponseCommandTask] (with 1 known super classes))
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [java/lang/String] (with 4 known super classes) and [com/amazon/inapp/purchasing/KiwiPurchaseResponseCommandTask] (with 1 known super classes)
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc]  at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:344)
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc]  at proguard.evaluation.value.IdentifiedReferenceValue.generalize(IdentifiedReferenceValue.java:65)
[2012-06-17 10:59:44 - sc]  at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:481)
...
```

I have the default ProGuard configuration file, and I have already added the:

```
 -dontwarn com.amazon.**
 -keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
 -keepattributes *Annotation*
```

lines to it. What went wrong?

Comment: Have you checked out this page? http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/2012/04/code-obfuscation-for-the-amazon-in-app-purchasing-api.html

Comment: similar question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061795/do-not-optimize-a-specific-class-path-with-proguard?lq=1

Answer (score 16):

There is some fishy stuff with the recommended config of Amazon.

1) `-dontwarn` is hiding a deeper underlying issue, where some Amazon specific libraries are not present, but referenced so that proguard will try some wired optimization which likely causes the above mentioned stacktrace.

2) `-dontoptimize` is disabling all optimizations, which is defenitivly wrong, because it is most probably just one specific optimization which is causing this issue, and proguards optimizations are removing alot of dead and unused code from your app and its libraries, so it shrinks the total dex size.

I guess fixing 1) is the real solution. This could be eventually achieved by extracting Amazons system libs from a device and make them present (as a provided lib) while building
the app.

For 2) you can try:

```
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {
    *;
}

-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
```

which solved the issue for me.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thanks for the `-optimizations !code/allocation/variable` part, it saved me a lot of time.

Comment: well I myself spent some time on that, so that was the least I could do to restore the world "time spent on stupid cover-ups" balance.

Comment: I'm talking to Amazon about some things at the moment. This is going to be raised as a concern in my next email.

Comment: Thanks! best answer! Works and keeps optimisations!

Comment: Thanks. Looks a lot safer than using '-dontoptimise'.

Comment: Worked for me too, thank you. However, it would be great to know which optimization is disabled with this code. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 15):

Per [Amazon's SDK Docs](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/sample-code/code-obfuscation.html), here are the lines you should include:

**Preventing Obfuscation of In-App Purchasing API**

When incorporating the In-App Purchasing API into your library, you will need to specify classes to 'keep' and not obfuscate. Add the following lines anywhere in your proguard.cfg file.

```
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

In addition, you will also need to skip Proguard's optimization step.

```
-dontoptimize
```

Note: Make sure to remove any other flags dealing with optimization, or any flag that may conflict with the above settings.

Comment: It sure is nice to have that link to the "primary source".

Comment: If I only use the default proguard-android.txt I can get my code working with optimization enabled. However if I use proguard-android-optimize.txt I have to skip optimization. And the end result is the same ie. APK is same size.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you will also need to lower the number of optimization passes to 1, or skip proguard's optimization step.

**-optimizationpasses 1**

or

**-dontoptimize**

Comment: ProGuard basically does two things (obfuscate and optimize).  Your solution is to disable one of them.  I'm not sure that's acceptable for people who go to the effort of enabling ProGuard in the first place.

Comment: This is not true.  I was able to get proguard working with Amazon IAP with -optimizationpasses 5.

Comment: @greg7gkb: hi, could you pls tell me what was the version of proguard in your application?

Comment: This was with Android tools revision 20, which is the latest as of now.

Comment: +1, regardless of the effect, this is in the official guidelines (https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/code-obfuscation#Setting%20Up%20Code%20Obfuscation%20for%20your%20Project).